# React Native Multi Chat Room Redux Structure

Tags: react-native, react-redux, asyncstorage

Hi have created a react application with 2 pages

1. list of rooms
2. chat page for room

I used redux to store the messages, the problem here all messages are showing on all chat rooms

Do i need to group the messages by room_id before storing to react?

I am confuse if we store message in Redux then why we need AsyncStorage as per the following tutorial

https://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-stateful-real-time-app-with-react-native-and-pusher/

Comment: no need for storing them on storage! the only thing you need as you mentioned is  grouping the messages by room_id before storing

Comment: But we are grouping before setting the data in Redux?

Comment: you will make diffrent id for groups and instantiate them as empty array , then you will assign the id to room id and push the messages to that group